# How to use String Variable to generate name of the lists and find the Length Pytho`

Tags: python

using string variable to create list variable names and get the length of each list

`list1=[0,1,9,10]`

`list2=[2,3,11,12,13]`

`list3=[4,5,6,7,8]`

`list4=[16,17,25,26]`

`list5=[14,15,22,23]`

`nn=1`

`l='list'+str(nn) #the result of this concatenation is **List1**`

`#this should give me the length of List1`
`;but it gives me length of bb variable`
`bb=len(l)`

`print(bb)`

Comment: don't use vairiables `list1`, `list2`, etc. but dictionary `data = {}` and `data[1] = [0,1,9,10]`,  `data[2] = [2,3,11,12,13]`, etc. or nested list `data = [ [0,1,9,10], [2,3,11,12,13], ...]` And then you can get `len(data[nn])`

Comment: I want to get the length of the Lists (list1...list19) therefore I am concatenating two variables l='list'+str(nn) which will result in 'list1' name of my first list then I will increase the number (nn variable) with the help of a loop nn+=1, to get name of my second list (list2), it works but when I want to get the len(l),it's supposed to give me the length of list1 which is 4, however it give me the length of string 'list1' which is 5

Comment: in python you can't create variable name using `'list'+str(nn)` but you have structures  `list` and `dictionary` to keep many elements and use number or string as key - ie.`data[nn]`

Comment: BTW if you will keep all on list `data = [ [0,1,9,10], [2,3,11,12,13], ...]` then you don't need `nn` but `for item in data: print( len(item) )`

Comment: BTW: example code https://pastebin.com/b5AZ92aT